# MySQL error: ' You have an error in your SQL syntax'

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

This code below gives me this error:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' where id = '000'' at line 1"
```

I don't understand the issue here

```
<?php
include(".conf.php");
$con = mysql_connect($conf['db_hostname'], $conf['db_username'], $conf['db_password']) or die (mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("aTable", $con);
$pr = $_GET['aThing'];
$pr = addslashes(htmlentities($prof));
$info_array = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM '$db' where id = '$pr'", $con) or die(mysql_error()); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $info_array )) {
    echo $row['aThing'];
    echo "</br>";
    echo $row['aThing'];
    echo "</br>";
    echo $row['aThing'];
    echo "</br>";
    echo $row['aThing'];
};
?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put table name into `FROM` : `SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE ....`.Also, you don't escape variable that comes from user. 
You will need something like :
`mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aTable where id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($pr)."'", $con) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Ok that got rid of the error but now it says `No database selected`

Comment: @JosephTorraca, remember this line?: `$db = mysql_select_db("aTable", $con);` ? change the value `"aTable"` to the name of the database you need to access, where `aTable` is from...

Answer (score 2):

Function `mysql_select_db` returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Instead, try:

```
$info_array = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aTable where id = '$pr'", $con) or die(mysql_error());
```

Or perhaps:

```
$dbtable = "aTable";
$info_array = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $dbtable where id = '$pr'", $con) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am pretty sure it doesn't have any errors with the exception of the
>   fatal error killing it.

I would say you'll get to a solution faster if you believe MySQL when it tells you there's a problem.

Re-reading the error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''' where id = '000'' at line 1

I would question the table name and the quotes around the id.  If that's an integer column, I'd expect to see a number without quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, `mysql_select_db` returns true or false. It doesn't return database name.